# To change the background from transparent to red using a bootstrap button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background from transparent to red when hovering on the button.

In html,

`<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" style="background-color: transparent; ">Click here</a>`

In css,

```
a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000; 
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

When I click the button, I can see the border colour changing but not the background. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles have higher priority and they will override your style on hover. Style the hyperlink through a class and then override it on hover.

```css
a.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
}
a.btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, it worked. So simple arrangement solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1) Make sure your custom CSS file is below the bootstrap file in your html document.

example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

2) It is better practice to style your html in a css document. Not directly in your HTML tags.

Try this:

```
a
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000; 
  background-color: #f00;
}
```